# alphabetically enumerate file lists with attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, enumeration

I'm trying to enumerate in alphabetical order two lists.

Issue being one 
For now I'm using zip to do as follows:

```
lista = ['A', 'B', 'E', 'R']
listb = ['C', 'D', 'F', 'G']

for elt, (contenta, contentb) in enumerate(zip(lista, listb)):
    print('[{}] {}'.center(79).format(str(elt), contenta.name))
    print('[{}] {}'.center(79).format(str(elt), contentb))
```

Now issue is that lista has a ".name" variable and that's what I'd like to print, however listb doesn't and I'd like to print listb directly (of course lista and listb are only used as examples)

So what I'd like to get is:

```
                                    [0] A                                    
                                    [1] B                                    
                                    [1] C                                    
                                    [2] D                                    
                                    [3] E                                    
                                    [4] F   
                                    [5] G  
                                    [6] R
```

However what I get is:

```
                                    [0] A                                    
                                    [0] C                                    
                                    [1] B                                    
                                    [1] D                                    
                                    [2] E                                    
                                    [2] F   
                                    [3] R  
                                    [3] G
```

I'm not sure how I would go to fix this? Is there anyway to sort and enumerate two lists while keeping the number consistent? And at the same time order it alphabetically?

Comment: But, `.name` is not an attribute of `str`. Could you give us more information about it?

Answer (score 3):

Sort `lista + listb` and `enumerate` on them:

```
lista = ['A', 'B', 'E', 'R']
listb = ['C', 'D', 'F', 'G']

for i, x in enumerate(sorted(lista + listb)):
    print(i, x)

# 0 A
# 1 B
# 2 C
# 3 D
# 4 E
# 5 F
# 6 G
# 7 R
```

Comment: Right yeah, just one issue left is that "lista" has a ".name" variable (as an example) while "listb" doesn't, so I'd like to enumerate "x.name" for "lista" and just "x" for "listb"

Comment: You forgot the brackets `[]` Austin,  Also your list is a list of strings, there is no `name` attribute present @Liam Please update your question

Comment: As @DeveshKumarSingh said, please update your question to show what you exactly mean by ".name" variable.

Comment: I tried to make it simple rather than too detailed, I guess that was the wrong move. I edited my question to be more precise

Comment: What's the issue? Now it's `alist.name + listb`.

Comment: I guess you got it. If not: `for i, x in enumerate(sorted(alist.name + listb)): print(i, x)`

Comment: Well since trying to be more general about my issue doesn't work. I edited everything to pin point exactly my issue

Answer (score 1):

It's processed at same time between elements of `lista` and `listb` because you use `zip`.
So, I recommend that making lists to one list first and sorting alphabetically.

```
lista = ['A', 'B', 'E', 'R']
listb = ['C', 'D', 'F', 'G']

listc = lista + listb
listc.sort()

for elt, content in enumerate(listc):
    print('[{}] {}'.center(79).format(str(elt), content))
```

The Result:

```
                                    [0] A                                    
                                    [1] B                                    
                                    [2] C                                    
                                    [3] D                                    
                                    [4] E                                    
                                    [5] F                                    
                                    [6] G                                    
                                    [7] R
```

Comment: Or just `for elt, content in enumerate(sorted(lista + listb)):`